# QTableView show live data from model

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to display a `pandas.DataFrame` content as a table using `QTableView` . I have a view-model which sub-classes `QAbstractTableModel`. This works fine.

I face problem when user updates the `DataFrame` contents (The application lets user to script and user can access the `DataFrame` directly and update it). I want to show the updated values in the GUI. I can do this by emitting the `dataChanged` signal. But there are so many methods to update an `DataFrame` that I am wondering why not have the GUI always display the contents of the `DataFrame`.

Is there any switch to do this? Or any other widget ?

I can register a QTimer and emit `dataChanged` every 1 second - Is there any better way to do this.

I think the equivalent model view classes in Android do similar to what I think.

Here is a minimal code. Here pressing the button updates the data-model,
but the view will continue to show the cached value. If I emit data-changed signal after the update, it would show the updated value. But I wan to avoid this if possible and want the view to show the data always from the `DataFrame` :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
import pandas as pd

from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class DFTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__()
        self.df = df

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.df)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self.df.columns.size + 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return self.df.index[index.row()]
                return str(self.df.values[index.row()][index.column() - 1])

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if col == 0:
                return 'index'
            return self.df.columns[col - 1]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        k = self.df.columns[index.column() - 1]
        self.df.set_value(index.row(), k, value)
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.column() > 0:
            return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    table_view = QTableView()
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
    model = DFTableModel(df)
    table_view.setModel(model)
    table_view.show()

    def on_button_click():
        print("Updated data")
        df.set_value(0, 'a', 33)
    button = QPushButton('Update data')
    button.clicked.connect(on_button_click)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(table_view)
    vbox.addWidget(button)

    main = QWidget()
    main.setLayout(vbox)
    main.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: What do you mean the user accesses the DataFrame, how do you do it?

Comment: The GUI app has an embedded interpreter in which user can access the dataframe and execute any Python command.

Comment: Can you subclass Dataframe then decorate the class to trigger the QAbstractTableModel to update? The events in the QTableView go the wrong way if the QTableView is the data output.

Comment: Provides an example of how the user directly updates the dataframe and uses the model.

Comment: Updated question with complete working code